# Grafana overwrite existing dashboard via API

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I'm trying to overwrite existing grafana dashboard via API, like this :

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api_key:xxx/api/dashboards/db" -d @test.json
```

And i'm facing an issue with versioning, cannot overwrite the same dashboard with my json :

```
{"message":"The dashboard has been changed by someone else","status":"version-mismatch"}⏎
```

Is there a way to avoid this and force overwriting ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That really depends what is in your `test.json` file. I expect correct dashboard model, so you just need to add a few fields to the top level, e.g.:

```
"overwrite": true,
"message": "my saved message, which will be available in the version history"
```

See API doc - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/http_api/dashboard/#create-update-dashboard

Comment: damn.. i was placing "overwrite": true in the meta part, not at the top level...

is there a way to put this line automatically in the json model ? i'm placing it manually after export and this is not very convenient...

Comment: @user2462699 I use python, where it is piece of cake. You may try to play with jq./sed/...

Comment: @JanGaraj can you share any python code snippet/example for this? would be great if it uses [grafanlib](https://github.com/weaveworks/grafanalib).

Answer (score 3):

Increment version field one time or several.

```
 "uid": "hDfaY-fGk",
  "version": 20            <-this one. Make it 21, 22, 23
}
```

Comment: The right answer.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for me. Still the same message.